# customizing `org-publish-project-alist`

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to publish webpage using org-mode. Two questions:

1. Is there a way to "sync" the org-mode files in the `base-directory` and the html files in the `publishing-directory`? Specifically, if I delete an org file in the `base-directory`, can I get `org-publish-html` to delete the corresponding file in the html directory also?
2. If I have pages within subdirectories, how can I specify a single `.css` file in the root directory to be used for the style sheet? For instance, my directory structure is as follows:

   public_html/

   - css/

     - mystyle.css
   - index.html
   - subdir/

     - index.html

With the following specifications in `org-publish-project-alist` (this is just a subset) --

```
:publishing-directory "public_html"
:style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/mystyle.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>"
```

`mystyle.css` is used by `public_html/index.html` but not by `public_html/subdir/index.html`. Is there a simple remedy to this (I want the style sheet to be used by both/all files in subdirectories)?

Thanks much ~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no straightforward way of doing this.  `Org-mode` doesn't know (or care) about the location to which it is publishing - it just sends things there and makes sure the correct directory structure exists.  There is a hook in the publishing process that gets called after the files have been pushed to their published location.  This is controlled by setting the `:completion-function` property in your `org-publish-project-alist`.  You could use this hook to write a function that compares the **.org* files in your `base-dir` and subdirectories to the accompanying **.html* published files, and remove those **.html* files that don't have an accompanying **.org* file.

   I suspect this will be most easily accomplished by making your Lisp `completion-function` call a shell script that removes the necessary files.  If you are doing something fancy with the `:include`, `:exclude`, or `:base-extension` properties, you'll likely want your `completion-function` to grab the pertinent information from the `plist` and then pass them to your shell script.  [This org-mode page](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-layersmenu.html#sec-4) has an example `completion-function` that shows how to get property values for the `org-publish-project-alist`.  You would then need to pass them to your shell script.
2. There are several ways to do this.  Perhaps the simplest is to just override the default style sheet in each file with a line such as:

   > #+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheet.css" />

   for your first level of subdirectory files, and keep adding `../` as you get deeper in the directory structure.

   Another possibility is generate generic template files for each *level* within the directory tree.  [This org-mode page](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html#sec-6) gives a nice example of how to set this up.

   Lastly, another option is to use the `:preparation-function` property of `org-publish-project-alist` to define a function that will automatically change the style file for each file.  Again, this is probably best done by having the Lisp `preparation-function` call a shell script to parse the files.  I could imagine doing this with the Unix `sed` program to find a regular expression denoted something like `href="@MYLOC@/stylesheet.css" />` and substitute the stuff between `@`'s with the appropriate level within the directory tree.  This seems like overkill, given the other options.